# How to get to errno in .NET Core 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net-core, serial-port

I'm using libc calls from .NET Core 2.0 to get to serial port functionality on Linux.

I'm importing the libc functions like this:

```
[DllImport("libc")]
public static extern int read(int fd, IntPtr buf, int count);
```

Then it's called like like this:

```
int result = Libc.read(fileDescriptor.Value, readingBuffer, READING_BUFFER_SIZE);
```

The result variable will contain -1 if the read functions fails.

How can I get to the errno variable from C# / .NET Core 2.0 in order to get the detailed error code from the failed read call?

Comment: Formally errno is a global variable, in practice the preprocessor of a C compiler will rewrite it as a function that returns a pointer to the variable.  You have to look in the errno.h file for the libc you use for the exact name of this function, it ought to resemble `__error()` or `get_errno()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct code is something like this:

```cs
int fileDescriptor = Libc.open(deviceName, Libc.OpenFlags.O_RDWR | Libc.OpenFlags.O_NONBLOCK);
if (fileDescriptor == -1)
{
    var errno = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nicely done. Because the method name suggests otherwise, let me point out that it also works for retrieving `errno` on platform-invoke calls on Unix-like platforms.

Comment: With .NET 6 or newer there is also `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastPInvokeError()`. According to the docs: "This method is functionally equivalent to GetLastWin32Error. It is named to better reflect the intent of the API and its cross-platform nature. GetLastPInvokeError should be preferred over GetLastWin32Error." (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastpinvokeerror)

Answer (score 1):

For net6 on up there's [Marshal.GetLastSystemError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastSystemError). I'm using it like:

```cs
    public static int LinkHard(string originalFile, string linkFile)
    {
#if WIN
        if (!HardLink(linkFile, originalFile, IntPtr.Zero)) {
            return Marshal.GetLastSystemError();
        }
#elif POSIX
        if (HardLink(originalFile, linkFile) == -1)
        {
            return Marshal.GetLastSystemError();
        }
#endif
        return 0;
    }

#if WIN
    [LibraryImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateHardLinkW", StringMarshalling = StringMarshalling.Utf16)]
[return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static partial bool HardLink(
      string lpFileName,
      string lpExistingFileName,
      IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes
  );

#elif POSIX
    [LibraryImport("libc", EntryPoint = "link", StringMarshalling = StringMarshalling.Utf8, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static partial int HardLink(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str)] string originalFile,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str)] string linkFile
    );
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement the existing, helpful answers with a systematic **summary as of .NET 8**:

- In **.NET 5-**, **[`Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error)**  must be used, which - despite its Windows-centric name - also works on *Unix*-like platforms, as shown [in your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48496256/45375).
- In **.NET 6+**, the less confusingly named *functionally equivalent* **[`Marshal.GetLastPInvokeError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastpinvokeerror)** may **alternatively, and preferably** be used.

Both methods ***only* return a meaningful error number IF**:

- either: a P/Invoke method declared with `SetLastError = true` was just called.
- or, in .NET 6+: a managed method just called [`Marshal.SetLastPInvokeError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.setlastpinvokeerror)

---

Additionally, **.NET 6+** now also offers a **[`Marshal.GetLastSystemError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastsystemerror)** method, as shown in [djeikyb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76010895/45375).

- This method **returns the last (most recent) *system error*** that occurred - the value of the global `errno` variable on Unix-like platforms, and the result of calling the [`GetLastError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) WinAPI function on Windows.
- Because this method is ***not* tied to P/Invoke features**, it **also works with P/Invoke-mediated native calls that do *not* declare `SetLastError = true`** explicitly, as long as the native functions invoked set their errors via `errno` / [`SetLastError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-setlasterror) - which is true for all *system* functions.

---

As an aside:

- The **exception type [`System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.win32exception)** - despite its Windows-centric name - is **capable of retrieving *system error messages*** on *Unix*-like platforms as well. (Unlike with the `.GetLastWin32Error()` / `.GetLastPInvokeError()` pair, there appears to be no alternative type with a cross-platform name yet as of .NET 8).
- For instance, the following - the system error message for system error `2` - yields `The system cannot find the file specified.` on Windows, and `No such file or directory` on macOS:

  ```
  new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(2).Message
  ```